# How to tell if ODBC is being used

Tags: oracle, odbc, ado

I have inherited an older application to manage. I was told that it makes an ODBC connection and a different connection. I am trying to determine what I suspect - That it is all ODBC. Here are the two connection objects:

1-----------------------------

```
Function OpenConnection(ByRef vConn)
  OpenConnection = True
  On Error Resume Next
  vConn.mode = 1    ' Read-Only
  vConn.Open Application("DSN_MIS"), Application("DSN_MIS_USERNAME"), Application("DSN_MIS_PASSWORD")
  if vConn.State = 0 Then   
    OpenConnection = False
  End If
End Function

Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

If OpenConnection(Conn) = False Then
  DM1Active = False
Else
  DM1Active = True
End If
```

2---------------------------

```
If Request.Cookies("username") = "" Then
  s = LCase(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"))
  If Mid(s, InStrRev(s, "/")+1, Len(s)) <> "cisgweb.asp" Then
    Call ForceLogon()
    Response.End
  End If
End If

Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.mode = 1   ' Read-Only
conn.cursorlocation=3
Conn.Open Application("DSN"), Application("DSN_USERNAME"), Application("DSN_PASSWORD")
```

I have searched online and cannot find a definitive answer to the question - How do I tell if the connection is an ODBC connection?

Thanks 
Sam

Comment: It depends on what provider you are using to open the connection.  Please show the value of Application("DSN").    What type of database are you connecting to?